# Opening a file in browser in a new tab rather than downloading it?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, cross-browser

I have a controller :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "action=downloading")
public void downloading(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    String dbType = request
            .getParameter(JDBCConnectionUtility.DATABASE);
    String fileName = request.getParameter("fileType");
    String browserVersion = request.getHeader(Constants.BROWSER_TYPE);
    boolean bFlag = (browserVersion.toUpperCase().contains("MSIE 5.5"));

    Utility.downloadFiles(response, response.getOutputStream(), bFlag ,
            fileName);
}
```

And the downloadFiles method definition in Utility class :

```
 public static boolean downloadFiles(HttpServletResponse res,
        ServletOutputStream out, boolean bIE55, String fileName) {

    File file = new File(fileName);
    if (bIE55) {
        res.setContentType("application/download; name=\"" + file.getName()
                + "\"");
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "anything; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\";");
    } else {
        res.setContentType("application/octet-st" + "; name=\""
                + file.getName() + "\"");
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "anything; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\";");
    }
        logger.debug("stored the response");
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    try {
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] byteBuff = new byte[1024];
        while ((bytesRead = bis.read(byteBuff)) > 0) {
            out.write(byteBuff, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        out.flush();
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        logger.error(exc.getStackTrace());
        return false;
    } finally {
        closeStream(bis);
    }

        logger.debug("In the download files Exit");
    return true;
}
```

My code snippet downloads the required log file. The expected case is that the required log file should open as a new tab in the browser window. How can I achieve this by modifying the code?

Answer (score 2):

Try below changes,

> 1. To open in a browser instead of downloading:

From:

```
 res.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "anything; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\";");
```

To:

```
 res.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "inline; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\";");
```

> 2. To open in a new tab:

Add `target="_blank"` attribute

If in case of form submission

```
<form method="post" action="/urlhere"  target="_blank">
```

If in case of the anchor tag

```
<a href="/urlhere" target="_blank"/>
```